# Isn't the padding in python HMAC wrong?

Tags: python, hash, cryptography, hmac

At the top of hmac.py are the lines:

```
trans_5C = "".join ([chr (x ^ 0x5C) for x in xrange(256)])
trans_36 = "".join ([chr (x ^ 0x36) for x in xrange(256)])
```

But the [HMAC RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104) (and every other source I could find) states that the inner and outer padding should be the bytes 0x5C and 0x36 repeated, not XORed with a range of numbers. That is, I expect to see:

```
trans_5C = chr(0x5C) * 256
trans_36 = chr(0x36) * 256
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Obviously if the padding is indeed wrong, then you would not expect correct output for any value. If you change the input or padding then a hash function is supposed to always generate an incorrect result.

Answer (score 3):

It's not incorrect. The code applies an optimization that is non-oblivious.

The code:

```
trans_5C = "".join ([chr (x ^ 0x5C) for x in xrange(256)])
trans_36 = "".join ([chr (x ^ 0x36) for x in xrange(256)])
```

Actually computes translation strings that are latter use to perform the XOR operations for the inner and outer padding. The code latter in the `HMAC` class's `__init__` does the XOR operations indirectly via the translate function and the precomputed strings:

```
    self.outer.update(key.translate(trans_5C))
    self.inner.update(key.translate(trans_36))
```

Lets then look at what `key.translate(trans_5C)` does:

> [`str.translate(table[, deletechars])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate)
>
> Return a copy of the string where all characters occurring in the optional argument `deletechars` are removed, and the remaining characters have been mapped through the given translation table, which must be a string of length 256.

It can be shown that `key.translate(trans_5C)` is an optimized version of:

```
''.join(chr(ord(k) ^ 0x5C) for k in key)
```

Thereby:

```
>>> trans_5C = "".join ([chr (x ^ 0x5C) for x in xrange(256)])
>>> key = '0123456789'
>>> key.translate(trans_5C)
'lmnohijkde'
>>> ''.join(chr(ord(k) ^ 0x5C) for k in key)
'lmnohijkde'
```

The value of those two expressions is the same. The same holds if `0x5C` is replaced with `0x36`.